# CodeBetter.com like blogs for Java

Tags: java, resources, blogs

I'm moving from .Net to java. So i wanted to know any good community blog site like CodeBetter.com, of java developers.

EDIT: i'm looking for something more than just coding examples, like CodeBetter.com or Artima.com, which influence your thinking.